# Function not acting the same way when run twice

Tags: php

I made a function that basically separates out some php variables on a document then pieces them back together after altering one.

Runs fine if I call the function once but when I run it twice I cuts off some of the last segment. It also isn't the same amount cut off each time.

I was wondering if there was any reason for this.

```
function editvar($filename, $old_var, $new_var)
    {
    $tmp = fopen($filename, "r");   
$content=fread($tmp,filesize($filename)); 
fclose($tmp);

    $ex = explode('<!---->', $content);
    $expl = $ex[0];
    $expl = explode('"', $ex[0]);
    $expl[$old_var] = $new_var; // changed selected variable.
    $ii = 0;
    $ex[0] = "";
    foreach($expl as $value) {
        $ex[0] .= $expl[$ii];
        if ($ii < count($expl) - 1)
        {
        $ex[0] .='"';
        } 
        $ii++;
    }
    $ii = 0;
    $new_content = "";
    foreach($expl as $value)
        {
        $new_content .= $ex[$ii];
        if ($ii < count($ex) - 1)
        {
        $new_content .= '<!---->';
        }
        $ii++;
    }
    $tmp = fopen($filename, "w");    
fwrite($tmp, $new_content);    
fclose($tmp);
}
```

well it starts off like: (at the bottom of the document)

```
<?php include_once "../../foo/foo.php"; ?>
```

and ends up like:  (after more than one call)

```
<?php include_once "../../fo
```

call to the function

```
editvar($root, 1, $var1);
editvar($root, 3, $var2);
```

Would it have something to do with the *fread*, because it using the same file the filesize is not changing to the new edited length, so it cuts off the end because the filesize is larger than the old filesize after being edited once. I hope that makes sense to someone lol - I am quite tired..

Comment: Indentation is your friend.

Comment: Additionally, add some sample date. Should we guess, what the desired behavior is?

Comment: And also the code that call the function...:)

Comment: This whole design seems fishy to me. String manipulation on this level is bound to get messed up.

Comment: ye it isn't the tidiest of things lol but I was more interested in why it cut some of the document off the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone actually cares here is what I did to fix this.

```
function editvar($filename, $old_var, $new_var)
 {
    $tmp = fopen($filename, "r");   
    $content=fread($tmp,filesize($filename)); 
    fclose($tmp);

    $ex = explode('<!---->', $content);
    $expl = $ex[0];
    $expl = explode('"', $ex[0]);

  // -----[my solution]
    $co = 0;
     foreach ($old_var as $value)
     {
        $expl[$old_var[$co]] = $new_var[$co]; // changed selected variable.
        $co++;
     }
  // -----[end my solution]

    $ii = 0;
    $ex[0] = "";

    foreach($expl as $value) {
      $ex[0] .= $expl[$ii];
       if ($ii < count($expl) - 1)
         {
           $ex[0] .='"';
         } 
       $ii++;
     }
     $ii = 0;
     $new_content = "";

     foreach($expl as $value)
     {
       $new_content .= $ex[$ii];
         if ($ii < count($ex) - 1)
         {
         $new_content .= '<!---->';
         }
       $ii++;
     }

     $tmp = fopen($filename, "w");    
     fwrite($tmp, $new_content);    
     fclose($tmp);
     }
```

Put all of the variables into arrays so *$intvar* (is variables to change) and *$Vars* (new variables)

now you only need to call the function once.

```
    editvar($root, $intvar, $Vars);
```